# Duplicate main menu for another language in UMBRACO

Tags: umbraco, translation

I followed this tutorial to assign different languages to a website (I have Umbraco 7.3), so I have now two pages: www.vcfm.mx and www.vcfm.mx/us/, but the navigation menu for both sites is still in spanish.

Is there a way to create a new main menu and assign it to the /us site? or, is there any way to change the language of the menu items in the /us page?

Thank you very much for your help!

EDIT: this was the tutorial I refered: http://carlosmartinezt.com/2014/06/umbraco-7-and-mvc-multilanguage/

Comment: What tutorial? Can you show the navigation code?

Comment: sorry @JannikAnker, I updated the post with the tutorial I followed :)

Comment: You should have created these as 2 top level nodes (i.e. www.vcfm.mx & www.vcfm.com OR www.vcfm.us) and then you could have set the Culture on the hostname per site. I think the issue is that it is picking up the former  culture that you have for the site you copied from.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how your existing navigation works, but I assume its similar to:

```
@foreach(var page in Model.Content.AncestorOrSelf(1).Children)
{
    <li>@page.Name</li>
}
```

If so, you will need to determine which root element to use. I would personally not use the URL to determine the root node but the following should do the trick.

```
@foreach(var page in Model.Content.AncestorsOrSelf(1).Last(p=> Model.Content.Url.StartsWith(p.Url)).Children)
{
    <li>@page.Name</li>
}
```

Rather than looking for a single Ancestor at the first level the second snippet looks up any root level nodes and selects the last one that matches the current URL.

*Unable to test the code.*